# O que é considerado falha no Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play

Acessei as estatísticas do meu app no Google Play Console e notei que há vários apontamentos de falhas, porém não há nenhum ANR e o crashlytics registrou pouquíssimos crashs, o que me leva a entender que estas falhas apontadas não são crashs, pesquisando na documentação vi que essas falhas são detectadas caso o usuário tenha marcado a opção de "enviar relatórios automaticamente" no Android...

Um ponto a notar é que não há nenhum relatório de erro apontando para essas falhas (enquanto que ANR mostram erros no play console), o que me deixa ainda mais confuso...
Se essas falhas não são crash, o que são?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

A palavra **crash** que você usou é muito relativa, até porquê crash em inglês significa falha.

**ANRs**

Se tratando das ANRs são aquelas mensagens que o usuario recebe de **O App não está respondendo.**

Um ANR será acionado para seu aplicativo quando uma das seguintes condições ocorrer:

- Enquanto sua atividade está em primeiro plano, seu aplicativo não respondeu a um evento de entrada ou como pressionar a tecla ou eventos de toque na tela em 5 segundos.
- Enquanto você não tem uma atividade em primeiro plano, e não terminou a execução dentro de um período de tempo considerável.

**FALHAS**

Um aplicativo para Android trava sempre que há uma saída inesperada causada por uma exceção ou sinal não tratado. Um aplicativo que é feito usando Java, trava se lançar uma exceção não tratada. Um aplicativo que é escrito usando linguagens de código nativo, falha se houver um sinal não manipulado, como o SIGSEGV , durante a execução.

Quando um aplicativo trava, o Android encerra o processo do aplicativo e exibe uma caixa de diálogo para informar ao usuário que o aplicativo parou.

Fontes:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/crash
- https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr
- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6083203?hl=pt-BR